# Android Studio Init doesn't seem to be working when attempting to use ondraw method

Tags: android-studio

DrawSnake.init() doesn't seem to be working. If I put "blue = new Paint()" outside the init() function, the app works perfectly well. But when I put it in the init() function (as shown below), it crashes with or without Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG. 
Is it possible to put it in the init() function without resulting in a crash?

```
package learn.test.snake;

import androidx.annotation.Dimension;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

//import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
//import android.graphics.Paint;
//import android.graphics.Point;
//import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.view.Display;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawSnake drawSnake;
    static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawSnake = new DrawSnake(this);
        drawSnake.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        //Object canvas;
        //drawSnake.onDraw(Canvas canvas);
        //System.out.println("in MainActivity");
        Log.d(TAG, "Main, before setContentView(drawSnake)");
        setContentView(drawSnake);
    }
}
```

```
package learn.test.snake;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawSnake extends View {

    public static final String TAG = "DrawSnake";
    private Paint blue;
    private Paint red = new Paint();
    private Paint black = new Paint();
    private Rect head = new Rect();
    private static int square_side = 20;

    public DrawSnake(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height){
        super.onMeasure(width, height);
    }

    /*public DrawSnake(Point screenSize){ ;
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
    }*/

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "in init");
        blue = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    }//no idea why but the app works without init.

    /*protected void onDraw() {
        onDraw();
    }*/
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        red.setColor(Color.RED);

        head.left = 30;
        head.top = 30;
        head.right = head.left + square_side;
        head.bottom = head.top + square_side;

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(head, red);
        canvas.drawRect(head.left - square_side, head.top, head.right - square_side, head.bottom, blue);
        Log.d(TAG, "in onDraw, before invalidate");
        invalidate();
    } 
}
```

```
2019-11-21 11:30:13.144 20555-20555/? I/earn.test.snak: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-11-21 11:30:13.315 20555-20555/? W/earn.test.snak: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-11-21 11:30:13.988 20555-20555/learn.test.snake D/MainActivity: Main, before setContentView(drawSnake)
2019-11-21 11:30:14.062 20555-20555/learn.test.snake W/earn.test.snak: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-11-21 11:30:14.062 20555-20555/learn.test.snake W/earn.test.snak: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-11-21 11:30:14.094 20555-20555/learn.test.snake D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-11-21 11:30:14.144 20555-20583/learn.test.snake I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-11-21 11:30:14.144 20555-20583/learn.test.snake I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-11-21 11:30:14.144 20555-20583/learn.test.snake I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-11-21 11:30:14.144 20555-20583/learn.test.snake D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-11-21 11:30:14.145 20555-20583/learn.test.snake W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-11-21 11:30:14.145 20555-20583/learn.test.snake D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-11-21 11:30:14.156 20555-20583/learn.test.snake D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe8785120: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
2019-11-21 11:30:14.162 20555-20583/learn.test.snake D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8785120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe87832e0)
2019-11-21 11:30:14.164 20555-20583/learn.test.snake E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-11-21 11:30:14.164 20555-20583/learn.test.snake E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-11-21 11:30:14.236 20555-20555/learn.test.snake D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-21 11:30:14.243 20555-20555/learn.test.snake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: learn.test.snake, PID: 20555
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Paint.setColor(int)' on a null object reference
        at learn.test.snake.DrawSnake.onDraw(DrawSnake.java:66)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20207)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3115)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-11-21 11:30:25.075 20555-20566/learn.test.snake I/earn.test.snak: WaitForGcToComplete blocked HeapTrim on None for 47.848ms
```

Comment: You never actually call `init()` anywhere. It won't run on its own. If you want the `DrawSnake` class to handle it internally, call `init()` from the constructor.

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thanks!!